# Powershell: how to suppress output of Select-Xml?

Tags: xml, xpath, powershell-5.0, select-xml

I assigned XML file contents to a variable `$config` and then used another variable `$market` to store the output of XPath query:

```
$config = Get-Content -Path "C:\files\configs\config.xml" -raw
$market = (select-xml -Content $config -xpath /process-config/input/filePattern/marketCode).node.'#text'
```

Then I add the following line:

```
write-host this is $market
```

And the output is this:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\xmltest.ps1

this is citigroup_ams 
#text
-----
 citigroup_ams
```

My desired output would be:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\xmltest.ps1

    this is citigroup_ams
```

I attempted to add `| Out-Null` at the end of the 2nd line but in this case only the output of Write-Host cmdlet was suppressed.
Is there any other way to suppress the output of `Select-Xml`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Show the full code (and the XML) that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: That being said, never use `Get-Content` to read XML files. `Get-Content` is just not smart enough to read XML files properly. Use `Select-Xml -Path $pathToFile` to read the XML file. It's also less to write.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this :

```
$config = [xml]@'
  <process-config> 
    <input> 
      <filePattern> 
        <marketCode>citigroup_ams</marketCode>
      </filePattern>
    </input>  
  </process-config> 
'@
$market = $config.SelectNodes("/process-config/input/filePattern/marketCode/text()").Value
Write-Host "this is" $market
```

Output : `this is citigroup_ams`

Comment: so you mean i will always have to manually put XML data into @' '@? What if i want my script to traverse through directories and extract data from multiple XML files. If I use '$config = Get-Content -Path "C:\files\configs\config.xml" -raw' in the first line and the rest is your code, then I get "Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'SelectNodes'"

Comment: Use `[xml]$config= Get-Content 'C:\files\configs\config.xml'` to load your data. If you have multiple items, use  `GetChildren` with wildcard `*` to select all your XML files then loop with `foreach`.